# TensorFlow 2 model.predict() output has incorrect shape: input data shape, not label data shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm new to TensorFlow and ML in general.

I'm trying to build a simple linear regression model in TensorFlow 2.9.1 (Python 3.9.12) that trains on chunks of daily weather data and predicts a specific feature. I have my dataset split into train, val, and test sets. I want to plot the values that are predicted from the `test_inputs` set, but the output of `linear.predict(test_inputs)` has the shape of `test_inputs`, not `test_labels` like I would expect.

The data I am working with has the following shapes:

```
<data>.shape = (years, days, features)
train_inputs.shape = (91, 245, 6)
train_labels.shape = (91, 1, 1)
val_inputs.shape = (26, 245, 6)
val_labels.shape = (26, 1, 1)
test_inputs.shape = (13, 245, 6)
test_labels.shape = (13, 1, 1)
```

I build and train the model as follows:

```
linear = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])

early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                                    patience=2,
                                                    mode='min')
MAX_EPOCHS = 1000
# Build model
linear.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
                metrics=[tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

# Train model
linear.fit(x=train_inputs, y=train_labels, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS,
                      validation_data=(val_inputs, val_labels),
                      callbacks=[early_stopping],
                      verbose=1)

# Evaluate model
linear.evaluate(x=test_inputs, y=test_labels)
```

I then try to get the predicted values from my `test_inputs` data set via:

```
predictions = linear(test_inputs)
```

I would expect `predictions.shape` to give `(13, 1, 1)`, but instead it gives `(13, 245, 1)`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`91`, `26`, and `13` seems to be the batch size of your dataset.

Try flattening your input -

```
linear = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(245, 6)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What does flattening the input do for me?

Comment: Converts your data from 2d to 1d

Comment: Why do I need my input data to be 1D in this case?